# Navigating through relations on two paths in schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord, eager-loading

From top to bottom I have the belongs_to relationship between my tables , and well has_many from the other direction.

```
ReportTarget
Report  
Manager
Organization
```

and

```
Score
Manager
Organization
```

so notice that `Report` table and `Score` table are kind of on the same level. They both have `Manager` Table as their parent.

Individually I could figure out how to navigate them with eager loading.
For first one I will do:

```
@blah = Organization.includes(managers: { reports: :report_targets }).find(params[:id])
```

and for the second one I can do this:

```
@blah = Organization.includes([managers: :scores]).find(params[:id])
```

But because I am doing with in my controller and want to pass the JSON to JBuilder, I don't know how to pass both of them? or maybe combine them together? such that resulting hash would have them in one hash but with separate keys:

```
{
  "firstoneinfo" : [
     # stuff that first json returns, can have their own internal hashes
     ],
   "SecondOneinfo : [
    #stuff that second json returns, can have their own internal hashes
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two different instance variables,

```
@firstoneinfo =  Organization.includes(managers: { reports: :report_targets }).find(params[:id])
@SecondOneInfo = Organization.includes([managers: :scores]).find(params[:id])
```

and then just use those inside the .json.jbuilder view file

Comment: so I do a respond_to, respond_with in the controller and passing it to json.jbuilder... for example respond_with(@blah) .... you mean I can also pass like respond_with(@firstone, @secondone) ?